# Override Material-UI Accordion Elevation

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, styling

I would like all of my Material UI Accordion components to have elevation of 10.

I am unable to find how to override that specific styles. I have successfully been able to override another property, `marginTop`, on the Accordion component, like so:

```
const theme = createMuiTheme({
  overrides: {
    MuiAccordion: {
      root: {
          marginTop: 5,
      },
    },
});
```

But just adding `elevation: 10` under the `marginTop: 5` does not work. Why is that? What would work?

Answer (score 2):

`elevation` is a props, not a css property.

- Use `overrides` when you want to [override](https://material-ui.com/customization/components/#global-theme-override) global theme using css.
- Use `props` when you want to create default props for your component.

Below are 2 different ways to override the `Accordion` elevation:

```js
const theme = createMuiTheme({
  overrides: {
    MuiAccordion: {
      root: {
        boxShadow: `0px 6px 6px -3px rgb(0 0 0 / 20%), 0px 10px 14px 1px rgb(0 0 0 / 14%), 0px 4px 18px 3px rgb(0 0 0 / 12%)`
      }
    }
  },
  props: {
    MuiAccordion: {
      elevation: 10
    }
  }
});
```

### Live Demo

[image: Edit 66977436/override-material-ui-accordion-elevation]

Comment: Aha! Thanks, NearHuscarl! How did you know it was a prop not a css property? In particular, I'd also want to style the background color of the dropdown options of an Autocomplete...

Comment: `Accordion` uses `Paper` as a root component. You can see all props of the `Paper` component [here](https://material-ui.com/api/paper/#props). there is no props to style `Paper`'s background color directly so you have to rely on css @val1217